# Why, while compiling a program, it is unable to find tesseract?

Tags: compiler-construction, ocr, libpng

I'm trying to compile OCR 0.4, an optical recognizing program by Google.

As written in the readme file they require to:

> 1) make sure you have these packages installed (current Ubuntu/Debian
>   versions should work):
>       libpng (with headers)
>       libjpeg (with headers)
>       libtiff (with headers)
>
> 2) install iulib from http://code.google.com/p/iulib
>
> 3) install a current version of tesseract from the Subversion
>   repository
>       (http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr)
>
> 4) from the release directory, run
>       ./configure
>       make
>       sudo make install

I've done all their passages above then when I type "./configure" into the command line I get this error:

> checking for /usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h... no configure: error:
>   Could not find tesseract! Choose --without-tesseract if you do not
>   want to use it or specify the installation path with
>   --with-tesseract=

What I tried to solve this so far, is try to compile by specifying the tesseract path I got by typing `"which tesseract"`that gives me

```
/usr/local/bin/tesseract
```

So I typed `./configure --with-tesseract=/usr/local/bin/tesseract` and I got the same identical error.

Why am I getting this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT -
After I've used the method stated in the answer below I get the following error:

> Localhost:ocropus giorgio$ make Making all in . g++
>   -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"ocropus\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"ocropus\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"0.3\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"ocropus\ 0.3\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"ocropus\" -DVERSION=\"0.3\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_WAIT_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_FLOAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_WCHAR_H=1 -DHAVE_LIBZ=1 -DHAVE_LIBPNG=1 -DHAVE_LIBJPEG=1 -DHAVE_LIBTIFF=1 -DHAVE_LIBIULIB=1 -DHAVE_LIBPTHREAD=1 -DHAVE_LIBTESSERACT_FULL=1 -DHAVE_LIBLEPT=1 -DHAVE_LIBGSLCBLAS=1 -DHAVE_LIBGSL=1 -DHAVE_LIBBLAS=1 -DHAVE_FORK=1 -DHAVE_VFORK=1 -DHAVE_WORKING_VFORK=1 -DHAVE_WORKING_FORK=1 -DHAVE_DUP2=1 -DHAVE_MEMSET=1 -DHAVE_SQRT=1 -DHAVE_STRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRDUP=1 -DHAVE_STRRCHR=1 -I.  -I./include -I./ocr-utils -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/tesseract -DHAVE_GSL -I/usr/local/include/tesseract -DHAVE_TESSERACT -I/usr/local/include/leptonica -DHAVE_LEPTONICA  -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-write-strings -Wno-deprecated -g -O2 -MT glclass.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/glclass.Tpo -c -o glclass.o `test -f
>   './ocr-line/glclass.cc' || echo './'`./ocr-line/glclass.cc In file
>   included from ./include/glinerec.h:57,
>                    from ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:5: ./include/glutils.h:139: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:105: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:129: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:175: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:236: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:421: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:644: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1166: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1403: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1623: warning: ignoring #pragma omp parallel
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:275: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::IComponentConstructor’ has virtual functions but non-virtual
>   destructor /usr/local/include/colib/narray.h: In member function
>   ‘colib::narray& colib::narray::truncate(int) [with T = char]’:
>   ./ocr-utils/narray-binio.h:48:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/colib/narray.h:261: warning: no return statement in
>   function returning non-void /usr/local/include/colib/narray.h: In
>   member function ‘colib::narray& colib::narray::truncate(int)
>   [with T = int]’: ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:295:   instantiated from here
>   /usr/local/include/colib/narray.h:261: warning: no return statement in
>   function returning non-void /usr/local/include/colib/rowarrays.h: In
>   function ‘T colib::rowdist_euclidean(colib::narray&, int,
>   colib::narray&) [with T = float]’: ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:396:
>   instantiated from here /usr/local/include/colib/rowarrays.h:94: error:
>   call of overloaded ‘sqrt(float)’ is ambiguous
>   /usr/local/include/colib/iarith.h:345: note: candidates are:
>   colib::interval colib::sqrt(colib::interval)
>   /usr/local/include/colib/iarith.h:620: note:
>   colib::dinterval colib::sqrt(colib::dinterval)
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h: At global scope: ./ocr-utils/components.h:
>   In instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’:
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:306:   instantiated from ‘void
>   ocropus::component_register(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::MappedClassifier]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1795:
>   instantiated from here ./ocr-utils/components.h:280: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’ has
>   virtual functions but non-virtual destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h:
>   In instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’:
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:306:   instantiated from ‘void
>   ocropus::component_register(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::Float8Buffer]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1796:   instantiated
>   from here ./ocr-utils/components.h:280: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’ has virtual
>   functions but non-virtual destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h: In
>   instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’:
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:306:   instantiated from ‘void
>   ocropus::component_register(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::KnnClassifier]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1798:   instantiated
>   from here ./ocr-utils/components.h:280: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’ has virtual
>   functions but non-virtual destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h: In
>   instantiation of ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’:
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:306:   instantiated from ‘void
>   ocropus::component_register(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::BitNN]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1799:   instantiated from here
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:280: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’ has virtual
>   functions but non-virtual destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h: In
>   instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’:
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:306:   instantiated from ‘void
>   ocropus::component_register(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::AutoMlpClassifier]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1801:
>   instantiated from here ./ocr-utils/components.h:280: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’ has
>   virtual functions but non-virtual destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h:
>   In instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew2’: ./ocr-utils/components.h:310:
>   instantiated from ‘void ocropus::component_register2(const char*,
>   bool) [with T = glinerec::MappedClassifier, S =
>   glinerec::AutoMlpClassifier]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1802:
>   instantiated from here ./ocr-utils/components.h:286: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew2’ has virtual functions but non-virtual
>   destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h: In instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’:
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:306:   instantiated from ‘void
>   ocropus::component_register(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::AdaBoost]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1804:   instantiated from
>   here ./ocr-utils/components.h:280: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’ has virtual
>   functions but non-virtual destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h: In
>   instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew2’: ./ocr-utils/components.h:310:   instantiated
>   from ‘void ocropus::component_register2(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::MappedClassifier, S = glinerec::AdaBoost]’
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1805:   instantiated from here
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:286: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew2’ has virtual functions but non-virtual destructor
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h: In instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’:
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:306:   instantiated from ‘void
>   ocropus::component_register(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::CascadedMLP]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1807:   instantiated
>   from here ./ocr-utils/components.h:280: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’ has virtual
>   functions but non-virtual destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h: In
>   instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew2’: ./ocr-utils/components.h:310:   instantiated
>   from ‘void ocropus::component_register2(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::MappedClassifier, S = glinerec::CascadedMLP]’
>   ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1808:   instantiated from here
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:286: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew2’ has virtual functions but non-virtual
>   destructor ./ocr-utils/components.h: In instantiation of
>   ‘ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’:
>   ./ocr-utils/components.h:306:   instantiated from ‘void
>   ocropus::component_register(const char*, bool) [with T =
>   glinerec::LatinClassifier]’ ./ocr-line/glclass.cc:1810:   instantiated
>   from here ./ocr-utils/components.h:280: warning: ‘struct
>   ocropus::ComponentConstructorNew’ has
>   virtual functions but non-virtual destructor make[1]: *** [glclass.o]
>   Error 1 make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation on [OCRopus](https://www.lrde.epita.fr/pipermail/olena/2011-December.txt), could you try:

```
./configure --with-tesseract=/usr/local
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer make me avoid that error but now when I use make it gives make[1]: *** [glclass.o] Error 1
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: I’m not seeing your error; can you edit your question and paste it below your current text?

Comment: I’m sorry, I can’t understand that error. I would suggest that you either leave this question open, or create a new question specific to that error, so that someone else may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Let's see if someone answer here :)